# calculate bitrate from video video

Tags: video, codec, bitrate

Im trying to calculate the bitrate from a video, but Im not sure if its correct.

I know that some of the formula is size divided with seconds on the movie. 
But shouldnt I calculate with the audio also ?
Or how does it work. ?

exp. I have a video size 320X180 , video bitrate 220(kbps) Audio bitrare 128.
What should the final bitrate be if the video is 10 minutes long (600s) and the size is 20mb (20480 kb)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20480kB*8(bits per byte)/600s which gives you 273 kbps to work with.
then you subtract out your audio rate... leaving you with 145kbps, not a whole lot for video rate. I would suggest looking at a lower rate for audio and upping video.  you You may also need to drop the rate a little bit to take into account the container overhead.

Comment: Hello. Thank you alot.
Im creating a couple of different videos to test how the different bitrates works, and how low quality I can have without get disturbe by it :)

Thanks you again

Comment: It depends on bitrate, quality required, video dimensions, and codec.  You will have to decide for yourself.